# Understanding CPU usage in linux using "top" command for VLC usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, vlc, transcoding

I have 2 quad core processors and I cant seem to understand what "top" is telling me.

I run a VLC transcoding application and i currently transcode 8 streams and "top" shows me that I am using 200% of my CPU. Now for a Pentium 3 that would be horribly bad but I dont understand how Linux calculates CPU usage with multi core processors.

Does this mean that my both processors are utilized 100%? 2 cores at 100%?

I also ran ffmpeg application for the same purpose and I could run 8 instances at 90% each which seemed to me like each processoss would occupy 1 core.

VLC has much lower CPU usage footprint so I just want to make sure I am not killing the hardware.

Comment: "I dont understand how Linux calculates CPU usage with multi core processors" One core is 100%.

Comment: So i should be fine at 800% CPU usage?

Comment: Well, that would mean all of your CPU is utilised. Whether that's fine or not depends... But that means that all 8 cores are on 100%.

Answer (score 2):

The output of top stating %cpu = 200 could be that of two cores at 100% or all eight using 25%

Being that you have 2 quadcores the %cpu would range from 0 - 800%